# Wt :: signals or binds?

Tags: loops, signals, bind, wt

i have loop to display a table with buttons.

```
WTable *my_table = new WTable();
int row = 0; vector<WPushButton*> buttons;
for ( vector<map<string, string> >::iterator it = data.begin(); it != data.end(); it++ ) {
 buttons[row] = new WPushButton("E");
 my_table->elementAt( row, 0 )->addWidget( buttons[row] );
 buttons[row]->clicked().connect( boost::bind( &this->process, WString::tr( (*it)["id"] ) ) );
 row++;
}
......
function ClassName::process( Wstring *str ){
 cout << str << endl;
}
```

the problem is on the binding of signal.

how to connect looped buttons signals to a function?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the signature of process() does not matcht the argument you try to bind to it: WString vs WString *. Does it work with

```
void ClassName::process( Wstring str ){
 cout << str << endl;
}
```